# Cannot receive e-mail when not logged in on ubuntu server

Tags: mail-server

recently I tried to set up an e-mail and web server with ubuntu server (postfix-dovecot and Apache2). When I'm logged in to my user account I can send and receive e-mails either internally and from internet. But when I'm not logged in, the emails sent from outside get bounced back to the sender with the following notification:

---

This is the mail system at host "domain".

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

```
               The mail system
```

user@domain: maildir delivery failed: create maildir file
    /home/user/Maildir/tmp/137969483152.P454754.domain: Permission denied

---

Am I missing something here?

Please bear in mind that I'm new to Linux/ubuntu.

Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1):

You probably chose to encrypt your home directory. If you're not logged in, the contents of your home are encrypted and inaccessible (as should be), which is why the MDA is having trouble creating/storing it in your home directory.

The easiest solution would be to change the mail storage format from Maildir (which stores mail in each user's home directory) to mbox (which usually stores in /var/spool/mail).

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem although I chose to keep the maildir format and to remove the encryption